# How to get sample rate, bit depth, and number of channels with Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am wondering how I can get the following audio metadata after uploading a file and embedding within `<audio>` tag.

- Sample rate
- Bit depth
- Number of channels

Is this possible with Web Audio API? Or do I need to parse the binary data of each audio file?

Comment: **(1)** _"...from **self-described** audio files"_ You and your _fancy_ English!! Are you asking how to read an audio file's **header** bytes according to the format's specs? **(2)** Are you locked to using C++? Using JavaScript, I can show you an example of how to read bytes of a **user-uploaded** MPEG files (via a File Browse pop-up) to get the required audio metadata. Here MPEG would be MP3 or M4A.

Comment: @VC.One **1)** Yes **2)** No! I would prefer to use Javascript to solve this problem. That would be great if you could show me an example.

Answer (score 3):

After researching this, I could not find a currently-available API for obtaining the metadata without manually parsing the binary file headers.  I opened Git issue [WebCodecs #411](https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/issues/411) with the WebCodecs team. [WebCodecs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webcodecs/) is a new API that could potentially offer this metadata viewing feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [music-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-metadata)?  It appears to support parsing all of the metadata mentioned above and supports quite a few formats.